# SQL: Many-To-Many vs Column-Based One-To-One Relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I'm currently struggling with the database design for a website.

I have a lot of content that shows availability of some features per item.
Typically boolean values, that indicates if a feature is available or not. But they might sometimes also contain other predefined values. (fx. option, on contact)

- ✔ Feature 1
- ✔ Service
- ✖ Feature 2
- ✔ Power
- ✖ Automatic
- ...

All items will always show the same feature-list, just with different availability states. (true, false, optional, in future)

I'm not 100% sure about how to accomplish this.
What would be the best aproach for this kind of problem?

**Many-To-Many Relationship?**

```
items
    id - integer
    title - string
    content - text


features
    id - integer
    name - string

item_feature
    item_id - integer
    feature_id - integer
    feature_state - boolean / enum
```

**One-To-One Relationship with the features in Columns instead?**

```
items
    id - integer
    title - string
    content - text


features
    item_id - integer
    predefined_feature_1 - boolean / enum
    predefined_feature_2 - boolean / enum
    predefined_feature_3 - boolean / enum
    ....
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages?
Are there other design possibilities?

I feel like i'd overlooked something in this solution.

Scalability: It doesn't matter if the solution is not scalable for future appendages. The main purpose should be reducing duplicates and unneccesarry database entries, which imo would happen in a Many-To-Many Relationship?!

Comment: If you said ALL items will ALWAYS show SAME features, I will go with one-to-one relationship.

Comment: What's wrong with many-to-many?

Comment: Will you have dozens of things?  Or Millions?

Comment: If you end up with many:many, see [_these tips_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel consider i have 75 features on 1000 items, with 50 similar features (in average) checked/available. This would end up in having repeating entries over and over.

Comment: @RickJames How would this tip reduce repeatable entries? This is a pivot table (like mine above `item_feature` ), isn't it?

Comment: How would someone implement comparison of, lets say, TV's for instance. They all have (repeatable) features like HDMI, 4K, Curved, 3D, ect. If I try to design the database for this scenario, I again end up in choosing between column-aproach (pre-defined) oder many-to-many (which imo will grow enormous). Both rely on predefined features, because later added feature wont affect already added TV's features, even if they have this feature or not. Is there a recommended design pattern for this kind of problem? Which also as some beneficial Scalability-Features?

Comment: What "repeatable entries" are you talking about? `(item_id, feature_id)` is primary key in your m2m-table. Nothing can be repeated. There is no problem with 75k rows. Its not a big table. But 75 columns is a nightmare (even though i've seen more). If you need something more komplex like categories - you should to be more specific.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394867/how-to-store-60-booleans-in-a-mysql-database/35395685

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Your linked question/answer is definitely useful.

Comment: So can we mark this as a duplicate?